# Disable Command button until comboBox value is selected

Tags: c#

I have a comboBox (*cmbPortName*) and a command button (*btnConnect*).

You'd use the drop-down in the comboBox to select a *port* you want to connect to and then click *btnConnect*. 
I just want to disable the command button till a valid selection is made in ComboBox. I figured the best way to solve this by doing something like

> btnConnect.Enabled = True;

until a selection is made in the Combobox.

Is there a better way of doing it? I am quite new to the programming and still learning stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a SelectedIndexChanged event handler for the combo box. In the Visual Studio design view for your form, double-click the combo box, or double-click the empty space to the right of the event name in the "Properties" window:

[image: create event handler]

That will generate and bring you to this block of code in your form's .cs file:

```
private void cmbPortName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And then add whatever code you want to conditionally enable your button:

```
private void cmbPortName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This will enable the button so long as the selected value
    // is not null or an empty string.
    if (cmbPortName.SelectedItem != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbPortName.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
    else
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button at first.

```
 if(cmbPortName.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = True;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for the combobox selected item change, you can write btnConnect.Enabled = True there.